# What different ways can you shower with your dad?

Tags: shower-with-dad-simulator

There appear to be some unlockable game modes and some locked content (most namely noted by "Dadlockable content" and [LOCKED] in the main menu). What is it and how do you unlock it?

Comment: I'm not sure how the title even relates to the question...

Comment: @Nolonar If you've played the game, it'd make sense.